# Okta with Passport.js or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, restful-authentication, okta

I was looking into improving my sing-up and login workflows and I looked into `Okta`.

At the moment we are using passport with our custom database and customs strategies and sessions remote storage. It seems like `Okta` can be used on its own. I did find some custom libraries online to use it with `Passport.js`. I don't see why you would tough.

Anyone has any experience with `Okta` and any opinion on why you would use it with `passport` ?

Here is a `passport` library to work with okta: https://github.com/techstars/passport-okta-oauth-example/blob/master/config/passport.js

Here is a "simple" way of using okta: 
https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/okta-sign-in-page/nodejs/express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two links you shared does the same thing. Mainly, get id or access token.

The Signin widget can establish a session and get the token via this config:

```
Application Name    My Web App
Base URIs   http://localhost:{port}
Login redirect URIs http://localhost:{port}/authorization-code/callback
Grant Types Allowed Authorization Code
```

the other link you shared gets the same token via this config:

```
passport.use(new OktaStrategy({
    audience:     nconf.get("OKTA_AUDIENCE"),
    clientID:     nconf.get("OKTA_CLIENTID"),
    clientSecret: nconf.get("OKTA_CLIENTSECRET"),
    idp:          nconf.get("OKTA_IDP"),
    scope: ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
    response_type: 'code',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/okta/callback"
  }
```

so you should not need to use both of them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with passport.js, but I tend to agree with you, with Okta you might not need it. Okta can handle most of the authentication, depending on how your app is developed you might need passport.

For example, if you are developing a SPA app or something that runs in serverless environment, you could use a Bearer token from Oauth. If your app is older, you might need something to persist the session. So, maybe that is what passport does for ya.

Okta is about to release self service registration, which after email confirmation, or registration will create a Users Session.

https://support.okta.com/help/Documentation/Knowledge_Article/Okta-Self-Service-Registration-685599529

Don't know if that helps.